# are fresh squeezed juices bad for the pancreas?

Tags: pancreas, juice

I often juice at home (using a slow juicer) carrots and sometimes I add apples, some red cabbage, a small beet, on occasion oranges with ginger.

But my mom keeps telling me that juices are bad for the pancreas and that I should stop this, and instead eat more cooked food/vegetables, because that will be easier on my digestive system, also says all the doctors will tell me the same.

I searched, and can't find anything on the internet saying that juices are bad for the pancreas, I only find info saying that it's actually good for it